# Does Wordpress Support Using Named Pipes on the Windows Operating System?

Tags: database, installation, wp-config, local-installation, windows

Okay, suppose I wish to disable networking completely on a development machine running MariaDB 10.1.14, and instead use Windows' Named Pipes/Sockets. I'm using a local copy of Apache (2.4.23 x64 VC14), PHP (7.0.8) using mod_fcgid 2.3.9, and Wordpress 4.5.3, where Apache's root is `C:\prod\httpd`, PHP's root is `C:\prod\php`, and MariaDB's root is `C:\prod\mariadb`.

What would I enter for the `DB_HOST` constant in `wp-config.php`? Is it simply:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:/MariaDB_10.1');
```

Or do I need an absolute path to a file under Windows?

**Note:** I am currently using Windows 10 Pro as the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no sign of any support currently for named pipes in Wordpress,  [Ticket #32798](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32798) on the Wordpress Trac added functionality for using named pipes under Windows. However, because it awaits review, it is not currently part of the Wordpress Software, nor is it supported.